# How to handle rate limited API calls

Tags: python, rate-limiting

We are using multiple external providers using API, each has their own strategy, rate limiting, and rules.
I want to be able to call these API's without hitting the rate limit (because some of them "punish" me for calling them too much), across multiple environments.

Is there any package that knows how to handle it, or do I need to implement my own solution?

My attempted solution was to use a package that rate limits functions, but since it doesnt work in async to an external DB, this solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to either buy a rate limiter Sass, or roll out your own. If you are in complete control of all the code that calls those APIs, a Python library that could coordinate through redis, have a declarative configuration for the limits in a JSON or TOML file, and provide decorators or context-managers (objects to use on `with` statements) can be built in 2-3 days of work.  An answer here can just give general directions.

As you mention "multiple environments" such a solution keeping track of the rates in a centralized place is the only thing to do. And I reiterate that `redis` would be an appropriate thing to keep track of all ongoing calls - it is both performatic enough, and offer the needed atomic, distributedly reachable data structures to make this tracking less of a hasle.

For a single process, in a single thread, using asyncio, an asyncio.Semaphore` object might suffice, or maybe just a small specialization on one, that would delay realising the used resources.

This one can do (maybe the window calculation could be more optimal - but this is ok for a single worker):

```
import asyncio
import time
import sys


class WindowedSemaphore(asyncio.Semaphore):
    def __init__(self, value=1, window=60):
        self.__initial_value = value
        self.__window = window
        self.__last_window_start = 0
        self.__peak_since_last_start = 0
        super().__init__(value=value)

    async def acquire(self):
        # A fine grained, reasonable constant to use
        # for sleeping times as things happen:
        sleep_time = sys.getswitchinterval()
        # Hold the call to
        while (
            time.monotonic() - self.__last_window_start <= self.__window
            and self.__peak_since_last_start > self.__initial_value
        ):
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)

        result = super().acquire()

        if (now := time.monotonic()) - self.__last_window_start > self.__window:
            self.__last_window_start = now
            self.__peak_since_last_start = 1
        else:
            self.__peak_since_last_start += 1
        return result
```